# How to extract variables by using JMeter Extractor

Tags: jmeter

i'am using jmeter "Regular Expression Extractor",my response looks as below

```
[{"@class":"com.test.dto.BoardDTO",
      "ReadOnly":false,
      "author":"John",
      "id":"89BC331D723F",
      "isPublic":false
   },
{"@class":"com.test.dto.BoardDTO",
      "ReadOnly":false,
      "author":"Alex",
      "id":"FTH7JBDRF567",
      "Public":false
   }]
```

I need to extract all IDs of class:"com.test.dto.BoardDTO" in this case "89BC331D723F" and "FTH7JBDRF567"

Any proposition please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead of regular expression extractor

Add a JSON Extractor and fill in the fields as below

- JSON path expression: `$.[*][?(@.@class == "com.test.dto.BoardDTO")].id`
- Match Numbers: `-1`

This will return all IDs where `@class` value was `com.test.dto.BoardDTO`. You can validate it using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) & [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) combination.

Comment: Yes it works also with: $.[?(@.@class=='com.test.dto.BoardDTO')].id  
thank you so much